# Struggling to convert JSON string into an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization

I am struggling with how to convert the following price quote JSON data into a C#
object:

```
{"MyFeed":
{"@Provider":"SomeProvider","MMM":
    {"@name":"3M Corp","low":"194.80","high":"136.78","change":"2.80","pctchange":"0.22","ask":"135.15","bid_time":"20161104131845","bid":"134.80"}
}}
```

I created a C# class like so:

```
public class Quote
{
   public string Provider { get; set; }
   public Data Info { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public decimal low { get; set; }
  public decimal high { get; set; }
  public decimal change { get; set; }
  public decimal pctchange { get; set; }
  public decimal ask { get; set; }
  public DateTime bid_time { get; set; }
  public decimal bid { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in code, I am fetching the data using an `HttpWebRequest`, which runs just fine.  But the step to deserialize the JSON data doesn't work.. It doesn't throw an error, it just has no data.  That code is:

```
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("<request URL here>")) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Quote quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quote>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            lblPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", quote.Data.ask);
        }
    }
```

I stepped through the code, so I know the web request is working and returning a JSON string.  I just don't know how to structure the C# class to accept the deserialized data.  Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to use this [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: THAT is a pretty cool utility!  It generated the class structure, which I can then rename the fields of as desired.  Thank you very much for the reference!

Answer (score 3):

You should define the properties like this.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@Provider")]
public string Provider { get; set; }
```

And

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@name")]
public string name { get; set; }
```

You have dozens other problems, like your fields are not decimal in the json, wrong class structure. Here how your class should look like:

```
    public class MyFeed
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@Provider")]
        public string Provider { get; set; }

        public MMM MMM { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootJsonObject
    {
        public MyFeed MyFeed { get; set; }
    }

    public class MMM
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string provider { get; set; }
        public string low { get; set; }
        public string high { get; set; }
        public string change { get; set; }
        public string pctchange { get; set; }
        public string ask { get; set; }
        public string bid_time { get; set; }
        public string bid { get; set; }
    }
```

How you make the conversion:

```
RootJsonObject quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJsonObject>(json);
```

Comment: Dont forget about "public Data Info { get; set; }", looks like its name should be "MMM".

Comment: I don't get the option to format the JSON itself.  It's coming from a third-party vendor "as is", so I have to live with it.

Comment: @DanielAnderson I was talking that your class structure is bad and I re write it so it will fit the json which you receive from 3rd party.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate it, because that is what I was struggling with! (smile)

Answer (score 1):

- Use `JsonProperty` to specify the names in the serialized string.
- You need to wrap the whole Quote type in a different type as you are passing in an object that contains the object you are interested in.
- You need to specify how the `DateTime` types are serialized.

Here is a complete and working solution with your json.

```
class JsonTester
{
    public void Test()
    {
        const string json = "{\"MyFeed\":{\"@Provider\":\"SomeProvider\",\"MMM\":{\"@name\":\"3M Corp\",\"low\":\"194.80\",\"high\":\"136.78\",\"change\":\"2.80\",\"pctchange\":\"0.22\",\"ask\":\"135.15\",\"bid_time\":\"20161104131845\",\"bid\":\"134.80\"}}}";
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateFormatString = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
        };
        var quoteWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFeed>(json, settings);
        var quote = quoteWrapper.Quote;
    }
}

public class MyFeed
{
    [JsonProperty("MyFeed")]
    public Quote Quote { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    [JsonProperty("@Provider")]
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MMM")]
    public Data Info { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("@name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal low { get; set; }
    public decimal high { get; set; }
    public decimal change { get; set; }
    public decimal pctchange { get; set; }
    public decimal ask { get; set; }
    public DateTime bid_time { get; set; }
    public decimal bid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works nicely as well, and I appreciate the hint on making sure dates are properly parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Quote class should be Serializable. Either add Serializable attribute to it or DataContract attribute to it with DataMembers.